# Several items missing from Menu Bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar, preferences

On a MacBook Air M1 running Monterey 12.4 several items are suddenly missing from the menu bar, e.g: battery, date time, and more
I tried:

- rebooting the device
- run in terminal `killall SystemUIServer`
- attempted to perform the suggestions on this [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

without results. I could use some help.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed any tools to manage the menu or made adjustments to preferences on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

On the M1 and Monterey you have a very good tool to check things like this.

Make a new user account and sign out of your current user and sign in to the new account. Then you can test arranging the menu bar and dock.

Once you know if it’s just the settings on your old account - deciding to backup and restore your files or digging into that one section of preferences can be determined. Most likely it’s not the system that got stuck here.